# Leaking antifreeze

Tags: leak, antifreeze

So I had a leak from my upper  radiator hose last week. Replace it right away then yesterday it started to leak from the bottom one. Replace that one and now it is leaking  antifreeze some where else.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What really is your question?

Comment: What could it be? First it was the upper hose. It stop then it started on bottom hose n stopped n now it is leaking from somewhere else.

Comment: Replace **all** the hoses - they are probably the same age and need replacing.

Answer (score 3):

Because the coolant system is pressurized what you tend to find is that if you fix one leak the resulting increase in pressure in the system leads to another weaker spot failing - as @Solar Mike said in a comment this could easily be down to age. Coolant hoses are typically rubber and as rubber ages it grows less flexible, since the hoses are likely the same age they will tend to fail around the same sort of time.

It's probably not what you want to hear but you may just be better to bite the bullet and  replace the entire set of hoses.